# Best way to reverse string in c#

Tags: c#, .net, string

Is this the right method to reverse a string? I'm planning to use it to reverse a string like: Products » X1 » X3 to X3 « X1 « Products
I want it to be a global function which can be used elsewhere.

```
public static string ReverseString(string input, string separator, string outSeparator)
{
    string result = String.Empty;
    string[] temp = Regex.Split(input, separator, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Array.Reverse(temp);
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
    {
        result += temp[i] + " " + outSeparator + " ";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to simply reverse a string or reverse it with modifying certain characters like `»` -> `«`?

Comment: I'm calling this function like this: ReverseString("test » test2", "»", "«") it replaces the separator with outSeparator. I wanted it flexible that is why I use two parameters.. :)

Comment: Looks good to me.  Rather than looping through the string array (temp) why not call temp.Join(" " + outSeperator + " ")

Comment: If you're using .net 3 or later you might want to lookup extension methods. They allow you to 'attach' the static method to the class eg `String s = new String(); s.ReverseString("<<",">>");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
String.Join(" « ", "Products » X1 » X3".Split(new[]{" » "}, 
    StringSplitOptions.None).Reverse().ToArray());
```

EDIT: The updated version version will work if the components contain spaces (e.g. "Foo Products » X1 » X3")

Comment: Wow, very short and single line, like it... But I'm having error: "No overload for method 'Reverse' takes 0 arguments"

Comment: @Hasan, you need to add `using System.Linq;` to get [`Enumerable.Reverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Yes that seems to be ok.

About StringBuilder:
No need to use StringBuilder unless there are **usually** more than 4-5 elements after the split. If there are **usually** less than that then aggregation is fine.

Comment: Depends how many times this function is called... If it's caled within a loop then there could be far more than that..

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `StringBuilder` rather than just string aggregation, especially if this is going to be used a lot.

You can also use `String.Join()` to put a delimited string array back together.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html

Answer (score 0):

I used the following:

```
  /// <summary>
    /// From BReusable
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="items"></param>
    /// <param name="toStringFunc"></param>
    /// <param name="seperator"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string ToJoinedString<T>(this IList<T> items, Func<int, T, string> toStringFunc, string seperator)
    {

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++)
        {
            sb.Append((i != 0 ? seperator : String.Empty) + toStringFunc(i,items[i]));

        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static string ToStringFromCharArray(this IEnumerable<char> items)
    {
        return items.ToJoinedString(x => x.ToString(), string.Empty);
    }
```

with `stringValue.Reverse().ToStringFromCharArray();`